# How to send a x-www-form-url-encoded request using jax-rs?

Tags: java, jax-rs

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/7/run' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'start=1510630400000' \
--data-urlencode 'end=1526092400000'
```

The above curl command works however I am trying to do the same using `javax.ws.rs` but I get 406 error. Below is my code

```
        Form form = new Form()
            .param("start", "1510630400000")
            .param("end", "1526092400000");

        Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/api/7/run")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .post(Entity.form(form));
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);
```

Comment: .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) this sets the Accept header. 406 means Not Acceptable.

Comment: Also are you sure the server sends back text/plain?

Comment: So what should be the right way given the curl command that is working?

Comment: Remove the request() and accept(), and it will be equivalent to your curl request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like jax-rs client is configured to send gzip data compression. If the client does not know how to deal with gzip compressed data, it returns 400.

Solution would be disabling the gzip by calling `setGzipEnabled(false)` in `JerseyClientConfiguration.java`